# How to get all files containing substring

Tags: php, substring, filenames

Can somebody help me? I have many pictures with current name like : "black_abc","black_bcd","black_cde","white_abc". How can I get only file with filename contains "Black"?

Comment: Agoeng Lauw, can you read about [the accepted answer system](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)? It has to apply to any of your 11 questions. It's just a way to say thank you to the community that helps you. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[glob](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php) will help you find all files containing "Black" in their filename:

```
$folder = "images";    //the folder containing all your images
$pattern = "*Black*";  //the word you are looking for

$files = glob($folder. '/' . $pattern, GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $filename) {
  //Display all pictures
  echo "<img src='"$folder . "/" . $filename . "' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strpos($filename, 'black') !== false
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this [Make use of **`stripos()`** [*Case-Insensitive*]

```
<?php
$files=array("black_1","white_2","black_3");

for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++)
{
if(stripos($files[i],'black'))
{
    echo "Filename is $files[$i]";
}
}
```